# Simple django chat function

Tags: python, django, django-models

Im trying to create a very basic chat application using django. I am trying to create just a simple function for some one to post a message that updates maybe an array? im not to sure on how to go about this. help is greately appreciated

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='chatuser', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Messages"
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

Comment: Joe, this isn't really a question suitable for stackoverflow. If you have a specific question, please edit it into the existing post.

Comment: Like @JoshSmeaton said, your question is not suitable. Still, I'd like to give you a lead. The `Message` class should have a `sender` property and a `receiver` property, both should be foreign key to `User`. That'd be the most basic implementation. Also, `date` field should not be allowed to be `blank`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will rephrase the question again once I figure out how to gather my thoughts correctly

Answer (score -1):

A basic chat application built using django and ajax can be found in https://github.com/sivaa/django-sample-chat. Clone the application and check codes given in it.

Comment: it didn't work. an incomplete Django project with faults.

Comment: The project was last updated 9 years ago and it will not work without modifications to accommodate recent changes in Python and Django.